# Make Devise raise ActiveRecord exceptions in registrations controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to implement the devise registrations controller to accept AJAX logins with minimum use of overriding it. Currently it looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  clear_respond_to
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:name, :location)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:name, :location, :soundcloud, :youtube, :twitter, :bandcamp)
  end

end
```

The problem is, in Devise's registration controller, the create / update methods are called without the `!` (e.g. just `resource.save`)

This is not ideal as validation errors like duplicate names, email addresses are not caught and instead I get an unhelpful 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

Is their a configuation option or other easy way to make devise raise errors without having to overide the entire controller?